# The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding - ASP.NET: HTTP Error 500.19 – Error

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I was getting an error "Request Entity Too Large error- WCF Service". So that I added below lines in the web.config.

```
<binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
 <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
 maxArrayLength="2147483647"
 maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
 </binding>
```

It is working fine after adding in DEV. I have sent it to the same in PRODUCTION. I am getting an error

> The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does
>   not match the content type of the binding....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If indicates that an error page has been served instead of the response from the WCF service. It would be great to check that the user you are running the WCF client under has access to the resource. Check your endpoint binding properly (**wsHttpBinding**)